# socket.io send some data to server when connect android

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets

in javascript and node.js  i can send data to server when connect like this

```
var s = io('http://216.157.91.131:8080/', { query: "foo=bar" });
s.connect();

var c = io.connect('http://216.157.91.131:8080/', { query: "foo=bar" });
```

and in server i can get the data like this

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  var handshakeData = socket.request;
  console.log("middleware:", handshakeData._query['foo']);

});
```

now in android how can i do same thing ?
iam use

> com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.2

for android and its code like this

```
    IO.socket(host);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    client.on("id", messageHandler.onId);

    client.connect();
```

now if i add some data with connection like javscript its show to me error

```
          JSONObject id = new JSONObject();
          id.put("user_id", 51);
          IO.socket(host,id);
```

error message its

> cannot reslove method 'socket(java.lang.string,org.json.JSONObject)'

Answer (score 5):

i found sloution

```
 IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();

opts.query = "auth_token=" + yourDataValue;
Socket socket = IO.socket("http://localhost", opts);
```

and u can get it by

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  var handshakeData = socket.request;

  var data = handshakeData._query['auth_token'];
});
```